# Wicked PDF and Javascript loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

I have tried a number of methods to load jQuery and Google Maps API in to my Wicked PDF generator. I am trying to load an image of an address in the PDF. I seem to have an issue with the javascript tag not working.

pdf.erb file:

```
<html>
      <head>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" %> 
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=######"></script>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

      </head>
      <body>
```

controller file:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "location",
               :template => "pdf_generation/location_show.pdf.erb",
               :javascript_delay => 5000,
               :show_as_html => params.key?('debug')
             end
      end
```

show.html.erb file:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-12'>
    <div class='ibox float-e-margins'>
      <div class='ibox-title'>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_path(@location), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      </div>
      <div class='ibox-content'>
          <iframe src="<%= location_path(@location) %>.pdf" style="width:100%; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried debugging with no success. I may not understand the debugging method for this.
Now I have also tried loading jQuery min file from the CDN and also tried wicked pdf javascript include tag. When I try either of these approaches I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute: ["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q",       "--javascript-delay", "5000", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20171005-21437-hwy6l4.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20171005-21437-gop4gw.pdf"] Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag Error: Failed loading page file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20171005-21437-hwy6l4.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore) Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

I could really use some guidance. I have not been able to get any javascript files to load. CSS files have been a little difficult to, for instance if I try to load a local scss file it typically just won't load, it seems to just ignore it. 
(ie stylesheet link tag 'application' )

EDIT

I found the offending code. the FontConfig warning had nothing to do with the loading of any resource. It related to this code that I had been using to pass ruby variables to javascript:

```
var location = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"main": "<%= @location.main %>", "lat": <%= @location.lat %>, "lng": <%= @location.lng %> }');
```

I have modified the google map to show in the PDF now, however what I did isn't DRY, and it makes me think there is another way to pass the ruby variable to my javascript code. Any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: You have to remember that relative URL's will not work in a PDF file. They work in the browser as the browser knows what URL the document was loaded from.  For the javascript tag you can use `javascript_include_tag( javascript_url("application") )`. And in your views make sure to use the url and not path helpers (`edit_location_url` not `edit_location_path`).

Comment: This still doesn't seem to help resolve my issue with running javascript on the PDF. I tried it and I still get nothing new. What am I doing wrong? I need to get jQuery and load Google Maps API to render an image of the location.

Comment: Ok, so I did finally figure out how to use debug mode and my javascript/google map image loads just fine. So I guess that means from an html standpoint it works. So I need help with what is not crossing over to PDF correctly. I thought the html would fire first and then the conversion to PDF?

Comment: Yeah Rails renders a HTML template normally and then wicked converts the resulting string to a PDF. You may want to read the readme again as it goes into the problems of using the rails asset pipeline. https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#usage-conditions---important

Comment: The problem still persists though. Say I use an externally linked JavaScript library I still get the error in my question about fontconfig. Why do I get a fontconfig error?